# How to forego transaction fees as a baker?

Tags: baking, baker

> Like other validators ("bakers" in Tezos lingo), Google Cloud is
> eligible to receive transation fees but a spokesperson from the cloud
> services provider said the company will be foregoing the fees.

How does a baker can even forego transaction fees?

Is there a way to bake blocks and not get transaction fees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you include a transaction that pays a fee, then the only way to forego it would be to explicitly burn it or donate it.

You could also only include in your block transactions that do not pay any fees. While these typically aren't found in the mempool, there's nothing stopping a baker from getting its transactions somewhere else, e.g. through a web interface.

Note: I don't know what specifically Google intends to do, just laying out some possibilities.

Comment: thank you for explaining arthur